# How to filter dropdown in custom grid

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

How to filter drop-down in custom grid in my case its throwing error Below is my grid code

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{        
    $this->addColumn('attribute', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('Test'),
        'align'     =>'left',
        'index'     => 'attribute',
        'type' => 'options',
        'renderer'  => 'ModuleName_Namespace_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Test',
        'options' => array(
            '0' => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('Please Select'),
            '1' => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('On Hold'),
            '2' => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('Credit Hold'),
            '3' => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('Open'),
        ),
    ));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->getResourceCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

**ERROR:**

> a:5:{i:0;s:203:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'attribute' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_order_status` AS `main_table` WHERE (attribute = '1')";i:1;s:5177:"#0 /var/www/test
>   /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: shoe more details

Comment: isnt it just replacing "attribute" with your actual attribute name?

Comment: Please show more details. Specifically the _prepareCollection function.

Comment: I edited Question please take a look

Comment: Its giving error because there is no any field or attribute in your collection please check you collection first.

Comment: ok then please give more details.this is insuffient data you gave.

Comment: yes another column is static values in drop down i want to filter those values

Answer (score 0):

```
options' => array('Please Select', 'On Hold' => 'On Hold', 'Credit Hold' => 'Credit Hold', 'Open' => 'Open')
```

Why don't you just put each label as string? This worked fine for me.